# titanium crashing on build and run

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Since last update 7.5.0GA i'm getting this error trying to build on iOS

[ERROR] :  Error: Error parsing plist: Expected  entry
    at walkDict (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/plist.js:123:11)
    at toJS (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/plist.js:244:10)
    at plist.value (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/plist.js:285:4)
    at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-titanium-sdk/lib/tiappxml.js:483:32
    at Object.forEachElement (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/xml.js:32:4)
    at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-titanium-sdk/lib/tiappxml.js:481:13
    at Object.forEachElement (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-appc/lib/xml.js:32:4)
    at toJS (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-titanium-sdk/lib/tiappxml.js:432:10)
    at tiapp.value (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-titanium-sdk/lib/tiappxml.js:828:4)

### at new tiapp (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/node-titanium-sdk/lib/tiappxml.js:901:19)

```
at Object.run (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:60:8)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/simctl.js:604:20
at Object.whilst (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5227:5)
at trySimctl (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/simctl.js:598:8)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/simctl.js:200:4
at Object.whilst (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5227:5)
at Object.list (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/simctl.js:195:8)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/simulator.js:179:11
```

### at fireCallbacks (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:140:5)

```
at Object.run (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:60:8)
at find (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:97:13)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4096:9
at Object.process (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2344:17)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2252:19
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:119:16)
at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
```

### at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)

```
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:118:9
at _insert (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2250:13)
at Object.push (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2303:13)
at Object.findExecutable (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:114:8)
at findTeams (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:455:21)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3880:24
at replenish (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1011:17)
at iterateeCallback (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:995:17)
```

### at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16

```
at Object.run (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:60:8)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:447:22
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3110:16
at replenish (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1011:17)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1016:9
at eachLimit$1 (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3196:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1046:16)
at loadXcodeInfo (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:304:11)
```

### at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3880:24

```
at Object.run (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:60:8)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:267:22
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:98:4
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3888:9
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
at iterateeCallback (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:992:24)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3885:13
```

### at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:76:6

```
at Object.run (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:60:8)
at find (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:97:13)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4096:9
at Object.process (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2344:17)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2252:19
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:119:16)
at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
```

### at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)

```
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:118:9
at _insert (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2250:13)
at Object.push (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2303:13)
at Object.findExecutable (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/node_modules/node-appc/lib/subprocess.js:114:8)
at security (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:64:21)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3880:24
at replenish (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1011:17)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1016:9
```

### at eachOfLimit (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1041:24)

```
at magik (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/utilities.js:51:13)
at Object.detect (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/env.js:49:9)
at detectOSXenv (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/ioslib/lib/xcode.js:252:9)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3880:24
at replenish (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1011:17)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1016:9
at eachOfLimit (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1041:24)
at /Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1046:16
at _parallel (/Users/ginessanzsanchis/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.0.GA/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3879:5)
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update your node/npm version and try it again.

I am sharing my node version and acce info. You can match and update accordingly.

node version: 8.9.4
npm: 5.10.0
TiSDK: 7.5.0
Appcelerator CLI: 7.0.7

Or you can use below command.

> > **appc use latest**
> >
> > **appc setup**

Again you get any issue so please share your console log via "**appc run -I trace**" command.

Thanks,

Comment: node version: 8.9.4 npm: 5.10.0 TiSDK: 7.5.0 Appcelerator CLI: 7.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I Deleted all modules, I reinstalled them again, cleaned project and rerun...